# How To Clean a Development Build of a Meteorjs App?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

There are two command line programs to start/stop/manage your meteor app. There is `meteor` and there is `mrt`. As of the latest build (0.8.2 or so) it's really not clear what the difference is between these two, if any. Both seem to support the argument "help" like `meteor help` and `mrt help`. The output of both seems to be the same to me.

Sadly, I do not see a "clean" argument available when I check the help for either of these. What do I need to do if I want to achieve a clean build? One that would

1. Blow away all packages and re-install them
2. Blow away any compiled templates
3. Blow away all Sass/Less compiled output

I ask this because I find myself in some kind of dependency Hades right now and want out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor is still in a pre-release state. So the idea of packages is (still as of this post) not officially supported, though it will be soon. The meteor community stepped in to build their own way to use 3rd party packages and this is what meteorite does.

Most of the commands you give to meteorite are eventually passed to meteor which is why you see the same output.

The only (main difference is) `mrt add` which checks atmospherejs.com for packages first.

These two will be merged very soon (there is a branch on meteor on github called packaging which seeks to achieve this)

The idea of 'clean' isn't really there in meteor because most of the stuff is based on hot code reloads, so when a file changes its completely scrapped/(cleaned) and rewritten.

If you change a bit of code it will rebuild all this unless you have a syntax error.

Nonetheless if you want to 'clean' the build from everything you would have to do this in two steps (the meteor part and the meteorite part)

This erases some stuff in the hidden `.meteor` folder

```
meteor reset
```

Delete everything in `~/.meteorite/packages`

Delete all symlinks only in your projects `/packages` folder. Be careful not to delete the folders because these will have been put in by you/whoever made your project and wouldn't be from atmosphere or meteor

Then run `mrt update` to reinstall all the atmosphere packages from scratch